# mysql insert variables from foreach results

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

Cant insert the results generated from foreach loop into mysql database.
Im provided with xml file which contains few of the details which will help me generate next generation of url's to access detailed product xml files.
Im still in the begging.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.website.com/categories/xml/list.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->product as $product)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO Software (groupId,codeId)
VALUES ('$product->attributes()->groupId,$product->attributes()->codeId')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "info added successfully";
} else {
echo "Error inserting into table: " . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close(); ?>
```

Here is the error message that i get :

> Error creating table: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
>   Error creating table: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
>   Error creating table: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Im not sure if my syntax is wrong or i have to somehow generate specific value for each result.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Im looking for 2 days different solutions and could not find anything on my own to solve the problem. If you could even guide me what i need to be looking for would be of a great help. Im not sure how to close the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one large string, but should have two. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Software (groupId,codeId)
VALUES ('$product->attributes()->groupId','$product->attributes()->codeId')";
```

A better approach would be parameterized.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Software (groupId,codeId)
VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Much easier to read, and safer. You then just need to [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) the variables `$product->attributes()->groupId` and `$product->attributes()->codeId`.

Here's a rough example, (the `i`s are for integers, if strings change to `s`s. One letter per variable):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $product->attributes()->groupId, $product->attributes()->codeId);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can read more here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: The 1st suggestion have partly solved the problem but the rows does not contain proper results. The results for all created rows look like that: ()->groupId  ()->codeId
()->groupId  ()->codeId...

I will need to read and learn some more about binding before i test your next suggestions. Thanks!
I will let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: I made a test but im not sure if i did it correctly since i've got some mysql errors. Will need some more days to study and test.